# "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'product' of 'productDetails' as it is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently trying to display product data on the product screen. This is the error I'm getting in the console when opening a product details screen.

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'product' of 'productDetails' as it is undefined.

I'm not sure why productDetails is undefined. It should contain product details data.

Here is my code.

ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { detailsProduct } from "../actions/productActions"

function ProductScreen() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
    const {product, loading, error} = productDetails;
    const dispatch = useDispatch; 
    console.log("something");

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(detailsProduct(id));
        return () => {
            //
        };
    }, []);

    return <div>
        <div className="back-to-results">
            <Link to="/">Back to results</Link>
        </div>
        {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> :
        error ? <div>{error}</div> :
        (
            <div className="details">
            <div className="details-image">
                <img src={product.image} alt="product" ></img>
            </div>
            <div className="details-info">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h4>{product.name}</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        {product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        {product.price}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Description:
                        <div>
                            {product.description}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="details-action">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Price: <b>${product.price}</b>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Status: {product.status}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Qty: <select>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button className="button">Add to Cart</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
    </div>
}
export default ProductScreen;
```

productActions.js

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL } from "../constants/productconstants.js";
import axios from "axios";

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {

    try {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST});
        const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products");
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data});
    }
    catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload:error.message});
    }
}

const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId});
        const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products/" + productId);
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data});
    }
    catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.message});
    }
}

export {listProducts, detailsProduct};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially when the page is rendered productDetails state should be empty or undefined although you have dispatched detailsProduct in useEffect but it will take some time to get data from API request that's why you are getting the error. You can use productDetails without destructure

```
productDetails?.loading
productDetails?.product?.name
```

the question mark between productDetails and loading is Optional Chaining you can read more:
[Optional Chaining](https://medium.com/@efeminella/es2020-optional-chaining-nullish-coalescing-3e81855e3f5b)

**

### Updated

**

```js
function ProductScreen() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const data = productDetails;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log("something", data);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(id));
    return () => {
      //
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(productDetails)
  }, [productDetails]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="back-to-results">
        <Link to="/">Back to results</Link>
      </div>
      {data?.loading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : data?.error ? (
        <div>{data?.error}</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="details">
          <div className="details-image">
            <img src={data?.product?.image} alt="product"></img>
          </div>
          <div className="details-info">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <h4>{data?.product?.name}</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                {data?.product?.rating} Stars 
                {data?.product?.numReviews} Reviews
              </li>
              <li>{data?.product?.price}</li>
              <li>
                Description:
                <div>{data?.product?.description}</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="details-action">
            <ul>
              <li>
                Price: <b>${data?.product?.price}</b>
              </li>
              <li>Status: {data?.product?.status}</li>
              <li>
                Qty:{" "}
                <select>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
                </select>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button className="button">Add to Cart</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: Where do I put that in my code? I understand the explanation of why the error is happening but I don't understand how to fix it. Thank you or your help

Comment: I have added the code copy and paste it

Comment: Thank you. When I changed the code, I am now getting the error "error is not defined" on the line ") : error ? (" .

Comment: @Sara use `data?.error` instead of error on that line.

Comment: I thought that might be it so I tried that, and got an entirely new error "Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem." Thank you for your patience helping me figure this out

Comment: copy and paste it again it's fixed. You missed parentheses in useDispatch and we all are here to help each other

Comment: Thank you. The error is fixed, however, now the data is not displaying. All details are blank and the image is broken on the product page. There are no errors.

Comment: Check the API there might be a problem with it or there is no data you can check the console also